# Oracle Sql Logical Operator

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have a confusion.

If I write

```
where shipment_ID not like '6%' and shipment_id not like '5%' or shipment_id not like '3%'
```

So in the ouptut will we get shipment Id starting with 6 or 5

Comment: What are you confused about :) ?

Comment: "So in the ouptut will we get shipment Id starting with 6 or 5" is that a question you are asking?

Comment: Yes, Because of "OR" statement, The output contains shipment id with 6 or 5.

Comment: Your predicate always return all of the shipment ids regardless of their value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this:

```
where shipment_ID not like '6%' and (shipment_id not like '5%' or shipment_id not like '3%')
```